# How can I trigger a function with a ionchange in div?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know if exists any option of trigger a function when you fill some data from a specific div:

```
<div (ionChange)="Trigger()">
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="ListRooms" (ionChange)="GetRoomId($event)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let room of rooms" value="{{room.ID}}">{{room.DESCRIPTION}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>DATE</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="room_date" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
```

Comment: You cannot listen ionChange event on div.

Comment: `ionChange` is an angular eventEmitter for `ionSelect` and other ionic components.. Its not defined for native html like `div`

Comment: What option can i use for it ?